# Diferencia entre List y toList

Tags: lista, scala

Estoy aprendiendo scala y sé que hay dos formas de realizar listas.

```
val R = (1 to 3).toList
```

y

```
val R = List(1,2,3)
```

Cuál es la diferencia entre dichas formas y cuál sería la mejor?

Answer (score 3):

Lo importante es saber que ambos modos son correctos y que el compilador sabrá qué hacer para optimizarlo.

La primera forma, `(1 to 3).toList`, es un modo indirecto, pues se invoca el método `.toList` del objeto rango. El rango tiene que estar bien construido: elemento inicial menor que el final y del mismo tipo. Por ejemplo: `(3 to 0.0).toList` dará error por mezclar enteros y decimales, `(3 to 0).toList` da una lista vacía.

La otra forma, `List(1, 2, 3)` es más directa al invocar el constructor para crear la lista. El constructor sabe buscar el tipo más seguro para la lista. Por ejemplo, `List(1,2,0.0) --> List(1.0, 2.0, 0.0): List[Double]`.

Para este caso, es mejor usar directamente el constructor `List`. Cuando la lista es mucho más larga, `.toList` te ahorrará bastante trabajo.

Un modo mixto sería invocar el constructor de este modo: `List((1 to 3):_*)`. Al añadir `:_*` estamos asignando a `List` tantos argumentos como items tenga la secuencia. Casi seguro que el método `.toList` usa esta llamada para crear la lista, por lo que te diría que uses mejor `.toList`, que queda más claro.

Un último consejo: si vas a usar un rango de números, no hace falta que lo conviertas antes a lista. El compilador sabe que son secuencias y buscará la representación más adecuada según vea. Si lo necesitas más adelante, siempre podrás pasar a lista con el método `.toList

Por ejemplo:

```scala
scala> val seq = (1 until 2) ++ (3 to 4) ++ (-5 to -1)
val seq: IndexedSeq[Int] = Vector(1, 3, 4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1)
scala> seq.toList
val res8: List[Int] = List(1, 3, 4, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1)
```